# can't see pages with KnpPaginatorBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination, knppaginator

I got a form, that send post request and show paginated results. There are problems, when i want to see pages number 2 and more, because there sended get request and controller doesn't see form to create query. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using symfony(1.4) and I dont know if there's a big difference between 2.x

so let me discuss about it...

creating url's you should use

`<?php url_for('page/view?num='.$page_num) ?>`

something like that, then you can now use the `request` of your module

`@app/{apps_name}/module/page/{actions.class.php} or {pageActions.class.php}`

to your `view` method

```
public function executeView(sfWebRequest $request)
{
   $page_num = $request->getParameter('num');
   echo $page_num;  
}
```

you should get what the page number now.

one more thing, this only works in $_GET requests.

---

You should know how to use Routing, to configure atleast 3 parameters. It will help you to use $_POST requests.

Comment: Hi. I'm curious as to why you would still be using Symfony 1?

Comment: It's hard for a certain group of developers to move/push to a new version..I'm working for an agile team and we need an output everyday, we need make a web apps instead of re-review 2.x, a big cost and a big waste for us to re-write all the plugins we've made.

there's no big difference, they're still using PHP/YML/Doctrine.
------------------------

You can't move to a certain place wherein you're already satisfied, if we're interested around 3.x in the future, we'll move around that version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You have a looong wait for 3.x [Link to Roadmap](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html) I will jump from LTS to LTS from here on out. I don't have the same urgency to pump out code at all costs, though, so I understand where you are coming from.

Comment: daison12006013, thanks for reply.
but i'm using third party bundle, and it provide me instruments to make pagination easy.

Comment: i'm gonna try with get method

Answer (score 1):

I think easiest way would be to make the search a get request so that is in the url. Then the paginated links will have the search value too.